# ASP.NET MVC: Export CSV files, right click Save Link As doesnt work on FF and Safari(Always function name and html extension)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

View Controller:

```
public async Task<FileContentResult> ExportAllCSV()
{
    var stream = await _apiController.GetExportCSV((User as WebUser).AccountID);
    return File(stream.ToArray(), "text/csv; charset=utf-8", "Record_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv");
}
```

View:

```
<a id="export-record" class="btn-default" href="Record/ExportAllCSV">Export</a>
```

The file export correctly when I left click across most of web browser. For the right click, save link as on firefox. It popup a window to locate the file. In popup window it show File name: ExportAllCSV.htm and Save as type Firefox html document (*.htm,*.html,*.htm).

Comment: It does this because when you right click "Save Link As" you're literally saving the http link, not the file. The file is being presented from the API controller as a stream. If your link was a `file://` link and a http `a` link, your right click would work, but that would also defeat the purpose of serving the file on demand as a stream.